# Do WordPress websites get indexed quicker by search engines than a regular website?

Tags: seo, wordpress, search-engines, search-engine-indexing

I registered a couple of domains with the names of categories of products we sell.
I then installed WordPress in one of those domains and played around with it for a bit, and left it alone for about a month. There was a link on my regular website to that secondary website and  that website was also registered in Google Webmaster Tools, but that's that.

I then searched on Google last week for that product category, and to my surprise, that secondary website showed up in the 2nd or 3rd page on Google.

Now my question is do search engines index WordPress websites quicker?
I had given up on using WordPress for that website, since it's so simple, but should I use it, would it give me better results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my opinion:

Indexing of a website doesn't depend on type of CMS or technology you can use.

Indexing depends on *sitemap.xml* you submit to Google Webmaster Tools and links to your website. CMS or programming language of website doesn't take into account for indexing. Besides, it also doesn't take into account for ranking in Google results.

Moreover, WordPress with SEO plugin like [WordPress SEO by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) is a SEO-friendly CMS and many websites built on WordPress rank well in Google results. Personally, I often use WordPress in order to produce a website quickly and I rank well with it.

Thus, my opinion in your case is to choose solution in relation to your priority. If you want produce a website quickly, a CMS can be the best solution. Otherwise, if you have time and you want a professionnal website (white label, without link to WordPress in footer...), develop it by hands (in PHP for example) can be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

No WordPress websites are not indexed any faster than a static website or one running on a different CMS.

There are multiple reasons the page became indexed. First you linked to it. Second when you installed it there was an option to ping the search engines. This isn't Googlebot it's Google blog search but none the less who knows how Google uses that information.

Another point is Google is an ICANN certified registrar and has access to root servers I believe so they are notified or can at least find out when new domains are registered. So without even linking to your domain Google at some point would most likely stop by for a visit.

Now if the keyword in your domain name is pretty unique. And not many other sites have it in their domain name or are well optimized with copy for those words that also play into how and why you ranked so high for it. Basically if your site seems the most relevant you'll rank.

This isn't a reason to run WordPress. The best reason to use WordPress is because of how flexible the application is all around to manage a website. It is SEO friendly on a default install.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress sites are quickly indexed mainly because it has a template system with which you can add more SEO tags and it also has SEO optimized templates which will give better results. Another good thing with WordPress is that it has good widgets and plugins which can be easily installed and everybody can easily understand how to use them. You can add many interesting things with these widgets very easily and make your site very attractive. It also allows multi-user blogging facility and multiple blogs with single installation.