# Does Wordpress have any SEO benifits on sites coded from scratch?

Tags: seo, google, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do wordpress websites get indexed quicker by SE than a regular website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39092/do-wordpress-websites-get-indexed-quicker-by-se-than-a-regular-website)

I have heard SEO experts suggest moving sites to Wordpress for SEO optimization. Googling offers some perspectives that confirm this (like [this](http://www.warriorforum.com/adsense-ppc-seo-discussion-forum/417532-wordpress-sites-vs-html-sites-search-engine-optimization-point-view.html) or somewhat more dubiously, [this](http://www.blackhatworld.com/blackhat-seo/black-hat-seo/461697-penguin-ranking-standard-css-html-sites-vs-wordpress-sites.html)). Is this accurate? Some other places say that it doesn't matter, except that Wordpress configures all the meta correctly. In that case, what exactly must be configured?

Comment: SEO experts are always telling you stuff as long as you pay for it. Most things they suggest don't even work and I would call it snake oil to hire a "SEO expert".